# What is the Ignition Gazebo equivalent of WorldPose()?

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How could I get the world pose of a Model in Ignition? The closest I can find is

```
std::optional<math::Pose3d> WorldPose ( const EntityComponentManager &  _ecm) const
```

but this function only seems to be for links.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25760/what-is-the-ignition-gazebo-equivalent-of-worldpose()-?/) by [finolex1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/31369/finolex1/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's [ignition::gazebo::worldPose](https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/gazebo/3.2/namespaceignition_1_1gazebo.html#abd245284d472b010a46c7b592921fd91) from `Util.hh`, which will work for any entity that has a `components::Pose`. All models will have that component.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1